# Powershell get ad user days to expired password

Tags: powershell

I want to export days to expired password information. I have tried something. but lo luck.

if user is already expired then I want to display as "expired".

```
function accountExpiresToString($accountExpires) {
    if (($_.AccountExpires -eq 0) -or 
        ($_.AccountExpires -eq [int64]::MaxValue)) {
        "Never expires"
    }
    else {
        [datetime]::fromfiletime($accountExpires)
    }
}


$EndDate    = (Get-Date)


Get-ADUser -Identity "User" -Properties * | Select @{l="expiration_date";e={ accountExpiresToString($_.AccountExpires)}}, @{Name="RemainingDays";Expression={(new-timespan -start $EndDate -end ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))).Days}}
```

My Desired output:

```
name,expiration_date,remaining days
user01,never expires,15
user02,never expires,expired
```

Comment: Nothing to do with this question, but I just wanted to post an answer on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790646/powershell-unable-to-send-mail-html-message?noredirect=1#comment109302314_61790646), but to my surprise you have deleted it and also in your profile it now says _please delete me_. If I may ask, why?

Comment: Hi man, actually I will update my question. Because I noticed some stupid issues my script.  But , I have deleted my question to be correctly. sorry for my fault. won't happen again. Now , I am undeleting my question instead of new topic.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you're not leaving the platform. I'm not anywhere near my computer right now, so it can take a while before i can answer, but perhaps someone else will do so in the meantime. Happy coding and stay safe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I think this should do it:

```
$today = (Get-Date).Date
$properties = 'PasswordExpired', 'PasswordNeverExpires', 'PasswordNotRequired', 
              'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed', 'EmailAddress', 'CanonicalName'
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $properties |
ForEach-Object {
    $expire = $null
    if ($_.PasswordNotRequired)      { $remaining = 'Password not required' }
    elseif ($_.PasswordNeverExpires) { $remaining = 'Never expires' }
    elseif ($_.PasswordExpired)      { $remaining = 'Expired' }
    else { 
        $expire = [datetime]::FromFileTime($_.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed')
        $remaining = ($expire.Date - $today).Days
    }
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Name'            = $_.SamAccountName  # or $_.Name if you prefer
        'Email_Address'   = $_.EmailAddress
        'OU'              = $_.CanonicalName -replace '(^[^/]+/)|(/[^/]+$)'
        'Expiration_Date' = $expire
        'Remaining_Days'  = $remaining
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi theo , I assuming you understood me.  I am not asking "accountExpires".   I am asking "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" attribute.  So no issue expiration_date attribute.  There is issue `@{Name="RemainingDays";Expression={(new-timespan -start $EndDate -end ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))).Days}}`

Comment: @Arbelac Please see the new code. I misunderstood the question because in your code, you are also testing for **AccountExpires**, not the expiration for the **Password**.

Comment: thanks you very much. I have a little question. I want to add  `@{Label = "E-mail Address";Expression = {$_.mail}}`  within PsCustomObject. How can I add that?

Comment: @Arbelac I've added the email address. Cheers!

Comment: thanks again , actually , I want to add expression define  within pscustomobject. I have  `@{n ='OU';e={$_.CanonicalName -replace '(^[^/]+/)|(/[^/]+$)' }}`  how can I do that ?

Comment: @Arbelac I have added this in. As you can see, using `[PsCustomObject]@{ .. }` you can simply add properties between the curly brackets. BTW. attribute `CanonicalName` is also one that you need to ask for with the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet. To keep the code clean, I have put all properties in a string array now first.