# Powershell - Unable to send mail HTML message

Tags: html, css, powershell, sendmail

I'm using a powershell script that will create an HTML report of new deployed VM and send it as an email.
I have tried a lot of stuff so far. But no luck.  Unfortunately , I am unable to get mail. Where am I wrong ? 
Here are the relevant parts of the script...

```
$Date = get-date
$Datefile = ( get-date ).ToString(‘yyyy-MM-dd-hhmmss’)
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
# Variable to change
$HTML = "yes"


#Add Text to the HTML file
Function Create-HTMLTable
{
param([array]$Array)
$arrHTML = $Array | ConvertTo-Html
$arrHTML[-1] = $arrHTML[-1].ToString().Replace(‘</body></html>’,"")
Return $arrHTML[5..2000]
}

$Header = "
<html><head></head><body>
<style>table{border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-size:8pt;background-color:#ccc;width:100%;}th{text-align:left;}td{background-color:#fff;width:20%;border-style:so
lid;border-width:1px;}body{font-family:verdana;font-size:12pt;}h1{font-size:12pt;}h2{font-size:10pt;}</style>
<H1>VMware VM information</H1>
<H2>Date and time</H2>,$date
"


$Report = @()
Get-VM $row.ServerName | %

 {

  $vm = Get-View $_.ID
    $vms = "" | Select-Object VMName, Hostname, IPAddress
    $vms.VMName = $vm.Name
    $vms.Hostname = $vm.guest.hostname
$vms.IPAddress = $vm.guest.ipAddress

$Report += $vms
}

if ($HTML -eq "yes") {
$output += ‘<p>’
$output += ‘<H2>VMware VM information</H2>’
$output += ‘<p>’
$output += Create-HTMLTable $reports
$output += ‘</p>’
$output += ‘</body></html>’ }


Send-MailMessage -to $emailto -Subject $subject -SmtpServer $smtp -From $fromaddress -Body ($output) -BodyAsHtml
```

Last update :

But When I run each time script , I am getting duplicate mail like below.
it sounds like these values appends into the variable.

Mail body :

```
VMware VM information
Date and time
05/14/2020 17:24:51 
VMware VM information
VMName, Hostname, IPAddress
VM01,  Vm01 , xx.xx.xx.xx
VM02,  Vm02 , xx.xx.xx.xx
VMware VM information
VMName, Hostname, IPAddress
VM01,  Vm01 , xx.xx.xx.xx
VM02,  Vm02 , xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Comment: Start by checking that you can send any mail at all with `Send-MailMessage`. Maybe the SMTP server rejects the connection attempt.

Comment: if I send as attachment it works but it doesn't work as body

Comment: For one thing: **straighten the quotes**. You are now using curly thingies like `‘` and `’`. In a Word document they may look nice, but in code they can mean big trouble.

Comment: like you said I have edited these again. But no luck

Comment: @Theo  , what do you recommemded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I feel are not right.

The helper function `Create-HTMLTable` is called with parameter `$reports`, but that is a typo, because the variable is actually called `$Report`.
Also, the function creates html from an array using `ConvertTo-Html` without the `-Fragment` switch and then tries to remove the extra html that is put in.
When using the `-Fragment` switch, there would be no need for that.

Next, when building the $Report, you are using `$row.ServerName`, but that seems never defined.

Try:

```
$Date     = Get-Date
$Datefile = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd-hhmmss}' -f $Date    # not sure why you need this
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

# Variable to change. Make this a Boolean, so it can be used directly for the `BodyAsHTML` switch
$HTML = $true

# create Here-String templates for the HTML and for a plain-text output
$htmlBegin = @"
<html><head></head><body>
<style>
    table{border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-size:8pt;background-color:#ccc;width:100%;}
    th{text-align:left;}td{background-color:#fff;width:20%;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;}
    body{font-family:verdana;font-size:12pt;}h1{font-size:12pt;}h2{font-size:10pt;}
</style>
<H1>VMware VM information</H1>
"@

# the placeholders '{0}' and '{1}' will be filled in later
$htmlEnd = @"
<H2>Date and time: {0}</H2>
<p></p>
<p>{1}</p>
</body></html>
"@

$plainText = @"
VMware VM information

Date and time: {0}

{1}
"@


# get the report for the VMs
$Report = Get-VM | ForEach-Object {
    Get-View $_.ID | Select-Object @{Name = 'VMName'; Expression = { $_.Name }},
                                   @{Name = 'Hostname'; Expression = { $_.guest.hostname }},
                                   @{Name = 'IPAddress'; Expression = { $_.guest.ipAddress }}
}

if ($HTML) {
    # convert the report into a HTML table. Use -Fragment to
    # just the HTML for the table; no '</body></html>'
    $table  = ($Report | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment) -join [Environment]::NewLine
    $output = $htmlBegin + ($htmlEnd -f $date, $table)
}
else {
    $table  = $Report | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String
    $output = $plainText -f $date, $table
}

# create a Hashtable for splatting the parameters to Send-MailMessage
$mailParams = @{
    To         = $emailto
    From       = $fromaddress
    Subject    = $subject
    SmtpServer = $smtp
    Body       = $output
    BodyAsHtml = $HTML  # $true of $false
}

Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

The HTML output should look something like this:

[image]

<sup>The reason for creating two HTML templates is that we want to be able to use placeholders '{0}' and '{1}' and replace these later using the `-f` Format operator. Because in the first part there are style definitions, also using `{` and `}` characters, if we do this in just one template, all of these existing curly braces would need to be doubled, otherwise `-f` will not be able to find and replace the placeholders.</sup>

Comment: Hi Theo , I have new issue. did you have a chance to take a look?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61857643/how-to-send-notification-mail-via-powershell/61861367#61861367